# I have only one URL in my App.Is there any method kept URL as a constant?

Tags: swift, url, constants

I have one URL in my App.I called that URL in the App several times.Is there any method kept URL as a constant and used that response in through out the App in swift

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Constant class on your project which contains a class variable with your URL

```
public class Constant
{
    public static var MyURL: URL
    {
        return URL(string: "http://desapsptre.com")!
    }
}
```

Other approach it's create an URL extension

```
extension URL
{
    public static var MyURL: URL
    {
        return URL(string: "http://desapsptre.com")!
    }
}
```